# using dojo with phonegap application in android

Tags: android, dojo, cordova

I created an application using phonegap for android.I want to use dojo with phonegap application to make interface effective and userfriendly.I am new to dojo.I am not understanding where to start.Please can any one guide me how to start with dojo and create applications in android.

Thanks in advance,
K.Himabindu

Comment: this link and all it's series very helpful just follow it http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-mobappdev1/index.html?ca=drs-

Answer (score 2):

There are only few resources about [Dojo Mobile](http://dojotoolkit.org/features/mobile).

There's a good tutorial thats walks through the complete development of an app: 
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/

The best way to learn is probably to take some time and play with the [tests/demos](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.6.0/dojo-release-1.6.0/dojox/mobile/tests/).

If you're completely new to dojo you might want to look at a more basic tutorial.  Can't really recommend something here. Maybe this?: http://docs.dojocampus.org/quickstart/dojo-basics

Comment: ok..Thank you.I saw those links.But i didn't find how to integrate dojo into an application.For example when i developed phonegap app i included .jar file and .js file into my app and then used html,css to create app.Like that to make use of dojo script i copied .js files (dojo.xd.js,dojo.js) and created a simple html using code provided in http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/, android.css.But it did'nt work for me.Please help me how to set up dojo framework for android application.

Comment: Did you do the steps in this tutorial? http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/hello_dojo/

Comment: I saw that application it is working in android...Hello is displaying,alert with version is displaying,but sliding is not working.when i use dojo.require(dojo.fx) in code even alert also not displaying.What may be the problem??I copied dojo.xd.js into my application.Is that correct way of doing?or i need to set up anything?

Comment: and when i am using the android.css,even hello is not displaying in emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem.  It turns out that when the APK gets created any files that start with underscores don't get copied and dojo has many files that start with an underscore.  Until this is fixed I am doing the following

1. During development use externally referenced dojo

   ```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.1/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad:true"></script>
   ```
2. For the production application I will create a dojo layer file that contains all the objects I use so there will be no need for dojo to require any additional files.

Comment: this is [the android bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5343)

Answer (score 1):

[Eclipse Method](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-mobappdev1/index.html?ca=drs-)

[Maqetta Method](http://maqetta.org/)

Comment: Aside: When you complete your dojox.mobile app, you'll notice that the whole dojo family of libraries is in your mobile bundle. There are some experimental tools for stripping out unneeded dependencies, but the issue is still mostly manually addressed. Still, I personally prefer dojox.mobile over JQueryMobile. Finally, since a given appstore can reject an app for any reason, profitability and/or audience impact is really the most important focus (so perhaps worrying about bundle size is not so important).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Mobile tutorial at Dojo documentation site:
http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/mobile/tweetview/getting_started/

Next, get a copy of the Dojo boilerplate so you have the project structure pre-configured.
https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate

Finally, go to the Dojo Mobile demo site to see what is possible with Dojo Mobile and then pick and choose the controls you want to use from there.
http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/mobileGallery/demo.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner, you can learn dojo from

```
http://www.roseindia.net/dojo/
```

if you start learning from roseindia you feel like dojo is very simple.

but once after you get confidence, you can try example code from other tutorial site bcz some example from roseindia wont execute successfully